# Comparison between pointer and integer when using inet_ntop in c

Tags: c, sockets, gcc, type-mismatch, inet-ntop

From the "man" pages it looks like inet_ntop returns a string (const char*) which should be alright when comparing to `NULL`. However, in my program I get a compiler warning at the first line in this code block that says:

> warning: comparison between pointer and integer

. Assuming the correct parameters are being passed in, is there something wrong with this:

```
    if(inet_ntop(address->sa_family, numericAddress, addrBuffer, sizeof(addrBuffer)) == NULL)
    {
        fputs("invalid address", stream);
    }
```

Unfortunately I can't distinguish which one it sees as a pointer and which one it sees as an integer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you included the "arpa/inet.h" file?

The "arpa/inet.h" contains inet_ntop declarations. If you do not include it, the compiler will assue inet_ntop returns an int.

Comment: Why wouldn't it issue a function not declared or something?

Comment: @MattVaughan In C, if the compiler find an undeclared function it assumes it returns `int`. As you compare the returned value with a pointer (`NULL` is defined to be a `void *`) you get the warning. And of course there will be a mismatch with the function arguments as well, which can cause undefined behavior.

Comment: The C language (at least C89) has the concept of implicit function declarations, where a function without a prototype has the return type and arg list derived from its first use in a function call, and lacking that, it returns int and takes an unspecified but fixed number of arguments. You can add -Wmissing-prototypes in your compiler options.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! I will have to see what header I am missing.

Comment: @MattVaughan Always compile with `-Wall -Wextra`, that would tell you about such and many more things.